# Ultimately comprehensive

Tags: adverbs

I wonder if this *adverb-adjective* fits well

> There should be an **ultimately comprehensive** solution to global warming, or else, we will definitely suffer in the end.

Comment: Too many adverbs there, actually.  *Without a comprehensive solution to global warming we will ultimately suffer.*  ultimately = in the end.

Comment: I'd rephrase it as: *Ultimately, there should be a comprehensive solution...*

Comment: My goal here is to intensify the ''comprehensive'', maybe I have used the wrong adverb. How about: There should be an **optimally comphrehensive** solution to global warming, or else, we will definitely suffer in the end.

Comment: I think comprehensive is already comprehensive.

Comment: This reads like a variant of "more unique".  Either it's comprehensive or it is not.  Neither "comprehensive" nor "unique" come in degrees.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it works, although I think it sounds better if you instead move "ultimately" to more clearly modify the verb "be":

> **Ultimately,** there should be a comprehensive solution for global warming ...
>
> There should, **ultimately,** be a comprehensive solution for global warming ...

This way you're saying that, *in the end*, there should be a *complete, worldwide* solution.

Otherwise you're making "ultimately" modify "comprehensive", which sounds either *odd* or *slangy*.  Native speakers (at least some American speakers) occasionally use "ultimately" when they mean ["ultimate"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/ultimate), i.e., "the utmost" or "best":

> That ride at Disneyland was so **ultimately awesome**!

Aside from being informal, it's also somewhat redundant here, since the definitions overlap.  In casual conversation it may be fine to say "the most totally complete" solution, but not in a formal essay.

The problem with trying to *intensify* comprehensive is that it's already a superlative adjective. Either something *is* or *isn't* comprehensive -- which is to say, if it's less comprehensive, then it isn't comprehensive at all. Unfortunately the term is frequently abused by native speakers, so this is just one opinion, but in my mind comprehensive should need no intensifier.

Instead, you can add a related superlative adjective:

> There should be a **definitive and comprehensive** solution to global warming ...

I also like "optimal", but that raises the question whether an *optimal* solution would, by definition, be *comprehensive*.  I feel like there's some space between these terms, but it's debatable.

Comment: Yes, this answer is good. showing two possible positions for ultimately.

Comment: I'd like to make the **comprehensive solution** more intense by adding an adverb, coz, you know, we are dealing with the world problem here. Finding ''the best'' word could make the statement attention-grabbing, yet corrrectly expressed.

Comment: @JohnArvin  I live in Southern California,  where the local dialect is famous for adding "totally" to exemplify adjectives, e.g *That was **totally** badass, dude!*  So, when you use "ultimately" in this way, it sounds familiar to me, but might sound like *vernacular* to other native speakers.   A better option might be to say, "a **definitive and comprehensive** solution", since these terms are complementary.